# Differences between pointer created by allocating on heap vs stack

Tags: c, pointers

For the case we have something like a pointer to a list of pointers.

```
// Allocating on Stack
typedef char *list[10];
char **pointer;
pointer = (list) {NULL};

// Allocating on Heap
char **pointer = calloc(10,sizeof(char *));
```

> Am I correct with the way I have written the code above?
>
> Also if anyone could explain if there are differences between the behaviour of `char **pointer` made in both cases, if there are any at all?

Comment: the calloc'd memory will stick around after your function returns, though it may be "lost" (e.g. memory leak). the stack version disappears automatically when the function returns.

Comment: `pointer` behaves identically in both cases. *The thing `pointer` points to* might behave differently though.

Comment: Suspect some down votes are attributed to unfamiliarity with C11 and then assuming ill-formed code.

Comment: @chux I was under the impression that whatever `pointer1` points to is a temporary that only exists until the `;` but according to your answer (and AddressSanitizer and MemorySanitizer and Valgrind), I was wrong, so I'll delete my comments.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, code is valid C11.

```
  // Allocating on Stack
  typedef char *list[10];
  char **pointer1;
  pointer1 = (list) {NULL};

  // Allocating on Heap
  char **pointer2 = calloc(10,sizeof(char *));
```

`pointer1[0], pointer1[1]... pointer1[9]`: the first element is initialized to `NULL`, the remaining elements are initialized to a bit pattern of zeros - which is likely equivalent.

`pointer2[0Marc B], pointer2[1]... pointer2[9]` content is set to zero.  That is what `calloc()` does, if `pointer2` is not `NULL`.

Neither `pointer1[0], pointer2[0], etc.` point to any `char`.

---

Also note [@Marc comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277165/differences-between-pointer-created-by-allocating-on-heap-vs-stack/34277477?noredirect=1#comment56296473_34277165) about the longevity of the data.  Data at `pointer1` is only valid until scope is lost (like function return) while data at `pointer2` good until `free()`.

Comment: Would the first 3 lines of code allocate an array on the stack and just give me back a pointer to it? Or does it get allocated on the stack at all? Thanks

Comment: Stack and Heap are not part of the C spec.  It depends on the machine/compiler (both of which are unstated).  This first only declares a type (no code).  The 2nd lines declares a pointer.  3rd lines assigns that pointer to the address of the compound literal `(list) {NULL}` which is likely allocated on your "stack".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where a compound literal has been instantiated, it may have static or automatic storage duration.  Assume the following code (getting rid of the `typedef` to make things a little clearer):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char **pointer = (char *[10]){NULL};

int main( void )
{
   ...
}
```

In this particular case, both the variable `pointer` and the 10-element array of `char` pointers that it points to have been declared/instantiated outside of any function body, so they both have *static* storage duration; the storage is set aside at program startup and held until the program terminates.  *Where* this storage is allocated from is an implementation detail, but for ELF and PE object and binary file formats, the space is set aside within a memory segment other than the stack or heap.

If we change that to

```
#include <stdio.h>

char **pointer = NULL;

int main( void )
{
  pointer = (char *[10]){NULL};
  ...
}
```

The variable `pointer` has static storage duration, but the 10-element array of `char` pointers that it points to has automatic storage duration; the storage for the array is set aside at the entry of `main` and released when `main` exits.  Objects with automatic storage duration are usually allocated from the stack, but bear in mind that "the stack" is an implementation detail, not defined by the C language.

Next variation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  char **pointer = (char *[10]){NULL};
  ...  
}
```

Both `pointer` and the 10-element array of `char *` that it points to have automatic storage duration.  Both have storage set aside at the entry of `main` and both are released when `main` exits.

If you want the 10-element array of `char *` to have *allocated* storage duration (i.e., live on the heap), then you would write

```
char **pointer = malloc( sizeof *pointer * 10 );
```

Like "the stack", "the heap" is an implementation detail and not defined by the C language.

Storage for the array is set aside by the `malloc` call and held until there is a corresponding call to `free`.  Storage for the `pointer` variable is still either static or automatic based on the rules above.  The only way to create an object with allocated storage duration is to use one of `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`.